# max()function Capitals

Tags: python, function, max

What does uppercase and lowercase have to do with max function. When I ask it to print max in "Hello World", it print "r". But when I ask it max for "Hello world", it prints "w". What does uppercase and lowercase have to do with this?

Comment: The max function finds the maximum in a sequence, that being said, uppercase comes first in lexicographic order therefore when W is in uppercase then "r" is the greatest (maximum)

Comment: Lexicographical is like how a dictionary sorts. The rub here is that it is honoring the order by the character code. Some order must be established and there is no inherent ordering between uppercase, lowercase, symbols and numbers when trying to order each group in respect to each other group. You can see how this plays out in an ascii table like https://www.asciitable.com/. Lowercase has a higher character code/binary representation than uppercase.

Comment: @DaniMesejo that clears things up for me. So max finds out the latest (largest character in a string. If it's capitalized, it won't treat it as the latest. But what about "Hello world." Why is the max letter for that w?

Comment: Because w comes after r, to verify you can check the "int" values using the ord function

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the ordering of the letters on the keyboard.

Each letter is assigned a value, so if the capitals (A,B,C ...) come after then lower case (a,b,c...) then the values will be higher (or visa versa).

So capital W has a different value to lower case w.

Here us the ascii table with the ordering of letters and their numeric values:

https://www.asciitable.com/

Here you see `w = 118` and `W = 87`, so changing it from upper case to lower case increased its numeric value accordingly.